# Comment on the uniqueness of the solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, holder-inequality, holder-spaces

Consider the first-order equation given by $y' = f(x, y)$ in $I := [x_0, b]$ subject to the initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$, assuming $f$ is continuous everywhere it is defined and there exists $M > 0$ such that

$$|f(x, y_1) - f(x, y_2)| \leq M|y_1 - y_2|^{a} \quad \text{for some } 0 < a < 1$$

and for each fixed $x \in [x_0, b]$. Comment on the uniqueness of the solutions for such a problem.

I know some things about holder continuity i.e. if the exponent $a > 1$, the function has to be constant and if $a = 1$, the function is Lipschitz continuous which has unique solution. If $a > 0$, then the function is uniformly continuous. I am not sure how to solve this problem. We can say that a solution exists locally by Picard theorem, but what about uniqueness?

Comment: For $a=1$, you said it, uniqueness. Can you make an explicit example of a $f=f(y)$ that is, say, Hölder continuous with $a=1/2$? What happens to the resulting ODE? Reason on examples.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro $f(y) = \sqrt{y}$ is an example of such a function. how do i know what happens to the resulting ODE?

Comment: Right. Now this is a classical example of an ODE that does not have uniqueness. Try to find two distinct solutions to the Cauchy problem with initial condition $y(0)=0$.